# Expression Problem: Why are simple parameterized types a non-solution?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm studying the [expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem) at the moment and it seems like I'm missing something. I used a data-centered approach (i.e. OOP) as the basic setup and then introduced two type variables, one for each operand in `Add`. These type variables are bounded to subtypes of `Exp` - this constraint is further narrowed down, when a new operation is added. For example in Java this would look like this:

```
interface Exp {
    int eval();
}

class Lit implements Exp {
    int value;

    public Lit(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int eval() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class Add<T extends Exp, U extends Exp> implements Exp {
    public T e1;
    public U e2;

    public Add(T e1, U e2) {
        this.e1 = e1;
        this.e2 = e2;
    }

    @Override
    public int eval() {
        return this.e1.eval() + this.e2.eval();
    }
}

interface ExpP extends Exp {
    String print();
}

class LitP extends Lit implements ExpP {
    LitP(int value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String print() {
        return "" + this.value;
    }
}

class AddP<T extends ExpP, U extends ExpP> extends Add<T, U> implements ExpP {
    AddP(T e1, U e2) {
        super(e1, e2);
    }

    @Override
    public String print() {
        return this.e1.print() + " + " + this.e2.print();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExpP add2to3 = new AddP<>(new LitP(2), new LitP(3));
        System.out.println(add2to3.print() + " = " + add2to3.eval());
    }
}
```

Now, type parameterization is a very obvious and simple approach, so there must be something wrong with it. Which requirement does this (non-)solution violate?

I'm aware of correct solutions like [The Expression Problem, Trivially!](http://i.cs.hku.hk/~bruno/papers/Modularity2016.pdf) and [The Expression Problem Revisited](https://users-cs.au.dk/eernst/tool08/papers/ecoop04-torgersen.pdf), which are similar in structure. I merely strive for a better understanding of the topic.

Comment: The biggest problem with that in my eyes is the ducktyping and usually there is no way to express constraints on the types except by how they are used in the body.

Comment: I'm confused about how you feel like your example is solving the expression problem: you want to define a new method/function *over `Exp`s*! How do you print `Exp` expressions?

Comment: I am aware of your point, which is why I've linked two solutions that are very similar in structure. They both essentially create a second language with the desired operation.